# Why does `helm-find-files` change behavior depending on my current location?

Tags: helm

Normally when I run `helm-find-files` I'm immediately shown a list of files in the current directory. Sometimes, however, helm just gives me an empty window. I can start navigating my filesystem in that window like normal, but I have to start navigation from the root of my filesystem. It's as if helm didn't/couldn't figure out the directory of the file I'm editing.

For example, I see this problem if my cursor is at the very beginning of a typical HTLM file:

```
<!doctype html>
^ point is here
```

or at the end of a line with a meta tag:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
                          ^ point is here
```

If the point is anywhere else in those lines, `helm-find-files` works as expected. In those positions, though, it seems like helm gets confused.

So my question: Is this expected behavior? I know that helm is complex (heck, it's probably self-aware), and it may well be that this is the "correct" behavior somehow. If this is expected, can someone explain why? I just need a better mental model of what's going on.

If this is not expected behavior, I'll likely file an issue with helm. I just wanted to do some due diligence before that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

helm-find-files tries to interpret the text at point as a file path or an URL. This sometimes is really helpful, since in a free flowing text with filenames you can just position the cursor and jump to the correct path. But it gets confused in some cases. A particularly nagging one for me is its failure to interpret a standard file URL like `file:/some/path` correctly - but it deals fine with `/some/path`. The leading `file:` seems to confuse it, while it again works fine with URLs like `http://some/url`.

Comment: Is there any way to turn this behavior off, or is it baked in? I've tried changing e.g. `helm-ff-url-regexp` but with no noticeable results.

Comment: I've opened an issue for this: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/870

Answer (score 2):

For this feature, Helm is using *ffap* ("find file at point"). Over at EmacsWiki, I found [advice on how to make ffap behave better in HTML](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileAtPoint):

> ### Ignore '/'
>
> On unix based systems, / is the root path. So all string starts with / is recognized as a path.
>
> This is annoying especially when editing HTML or XML. The following advice ignore / as a wrong result.
>
> ```
> (defadvice ffap-file-at-point (after ffap-file-at-point-after-advice ())
>   (if (string= ad-return-value "/")
>       (setq ad-return-value nil)))
> (ad-activate 'ffap-file-at-point)
> ;; (ad-deactivate 'ffap-file-at-point)
> ```
>
> – tomykaira, feel free to use this snippet in any way.

It seems to work great. Real filenames are still recognized, but false positives (which made Helm fall back to '/') are not.

Comment: How can I turn this on when the buffer have a major mode related to HTML activated?

Answer (score 0):

When your helm prompt reads "Find Files or URL:" and you want the other helm way of finding/filtering you can hit C-c / and you should get the prompt "pattern:" with the more normal helm find.

I also use this in when C-x C-f in dired goes to a funny helm prompt.